# Devise + Omniauth + remember_me

Tags: devise, omniauth, remember-me

There seems to be some confusion on how to get remember me working with Omniauth.

According to this [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Omniauthable,-sign-out-action-and-rememberable), you need to have the following in your OmniauthCallbacksController:

```
remember_me(user)
```

On the other hand, according to this [issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/776), you just need to do this:

```
user.remember_me = true
```

In addition, making remember_me default to true according to [this](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/12/rails-devise-and-remember_me-rememberable-by-default/), you just need to add the following to your User.rb

```
def remember_me
  true
end
```

Not sure which one is the official answer, and all three doesn't work for me. It only works for Chrome on Mac, but doesn't for Firefox Mac & Chrome Windows. Not sure what is going on.

My code looks like this:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

    include Devise::Controllers::Rememberable

    def all
        omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        auth = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
        if auth

            auth.update_with_omniauth omniauth
            auth.save!

            # ???
            remember_me auth.user
            auth.user.remember_me = true

            if user_signed_in?
                redirect_back_or settings_path(current_user)
            else
                sign_in_and_redirect auth.user, event: :authentication
            end
        else
            if user_signed_in?
                current_user.build_auth(omniauth).save!
                redirect_back_or settings_path(current_user)
            else
                session["devise.omniauth"] = omniauth.except('extra')
                redirect_to new_user_registration_url
            end
        end
    end

    alias_method :facebook, :all
    alias_method :twitter, :all

end
```

Answer (score 3):

This was answered [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3150) by [Jose Valim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588267/jos%C3%A9-valim).

> The first option is the correct one. The other two simply set the
>   default value of the field to true, which means it will be
>   automatically remembered whenever the first one is called.
>
> If it works in some browsers or not, it is likely a browser issue
>   because the server is definitely sending the proper cookies. Try to
>   confirm if the cookie is indeed correct and find out if the browser is
>   storing it properly.